# Generic doubt about the Simplex Method

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex-method

Let's say we are working on a LPP in the following form:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\min \quad &z = f(x) \\[.15cm]
s.a. \quad &Ax \leqslant b \\[.15cm]
&x \geqslant 0
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Is there any kind of restriction if we are working with a vector $b$ that has negative components? I mean, is it okay to proceed as usual when we are working with a negative $b$ vector? If not, how would we proceed in this scenario?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Yes, why would negative $b$ be a problem???

Comment: Okay, I see my question is pretty stupid now! Thanks for the help. Is it better if I close the question?

Comment: @roro Your question is not stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplex method does become more complicated when $b$ has negative components.

In general, the logic of the method is: start at a basic feasible solution (bfs), then move to an adjacent but better bfs, until the optimal solution is found. The key problem with this is: where do you start?

If $b \ge 0$, then the answer is easy. You start at the point $x=0$. (This is always a bfs; in the tableau, it corresponds to making all the slack variables basic variables.)

If $b$ has some negative components, then $x=0$ is no longer feasible. In that case, we don't even know if the system of inequalities $Ax \le b \land x \ge 0$ has any solutions! Finding a starting point for the simplex method is a problem just as hard as finding an optimal solution afterwards.

The usual solution is one of several *two-phase simplex methods*. Here, we start by creating an auxiliary linear program from the original one. The auxiliary LP is guaranteed to have a starting bfs. When solved to optimality, the result will either give us a bfs for the original LP (and then we proceed from there), or show that the original LP is infeasible.

Comment: So when we have some component in $b$ negative se should apply the two phase method and not proceed as usual? (Even thought slack variables form the identity matrix in the coeficientts matrix) ?

Comment: Correct. To have a bfs in the simplex method, it is important that all the basic variables have positive values. When some components in $b$ are negative, the all-slack-variable basic solution you're talking about would make some slack variables negative. If you kept doing the simplex method from that point, it's possible that you'd end up with a "solution" where some of the inequalities $Ax \le b$ and $x \ge 0$ are violated.